# JQuery - Change the href of the li a 's to javascript:void(0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I have a thumbnail list:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href=#c1><img /><p>1 Thumb</p></a></li>
  <li><a href=#c2><img /><p>2. Thumb</p></a></li>
  <li><a href=#c3><img /><p>3. Thumb</p></a></li>
</ul>
```

And javascript (i use jquery framework) should change every **href** of the **a**'s in the **ul** to **javascript:void(0)**

It's like:

```
$("#thumbs ul li > a").href( 'javascript:void(0)');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) (used for attributes, instead of `.href()`) like this:

```
$("#thumbs ul li > a").attr('href','javascript:void(0)');
```

...but I wouldn't, there's a better way to solve your problem, for example:

```
$("#thumbs ul li > a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

This attaches a property `click` handler to prevent the navigation, rather than messing with attributes to do the same.

Comment: 1., It's cleaner, 2., It's putting middle man between click and action, rather than modifying DOM.

Comment: @Sandeepan - for a couple of reasons, check out this question for a lengthier discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0 But there are other disadvantages as well, ever changing the `href` back, or using it for anything later for example...all prevented if you blow it away, when you can do the same action leaving it intact.